# How can I disable WIF cache?

Tags: wcf, wif

We are calling a third-party service using Windows Identity Foundation. The service is called between 30-40 times successfully. But memory usage of the client application is strange. The application is consuming more and more memory at each service call. I profiled the client application and I found that there are many `Dictionary<object,MruSecurityTokenCache.CacheEntry>.Entry[]`
 instances and each instance consumes memory. If possible then I don't want to use the cache. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved using the configuration below:

```
<system.ServiceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Client">
        <clientCredentials>
          <issuedToken cacheIssuedTokens="false" />
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.ServiceModel>
```